# How to Find Number of Roots within a Range For Functions That Are Not Polynomials

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, algorithms, roots, numerical-calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a univariate continuous function with a certain number of double roots. For any interval $[a,b]$, can you tell how much roots of $f(x)$ are in that interval? The specific function I had in mind was $$f(x)=\sin^2(\frac{n}{x}\pi)+\sin^2(x \pi)$$ where $n$ can be any integer.

**EDIT:** I will also accept an algorithm that can tell, within an interval $[a,b]$, whether at least one root exists there.

Comment: There is no method that can guarantee to find all the roots. I suggest creating a value table with small steps , lets say $0.1$ , and looking for sign changes.

Comment: @Peter That may be a problem when the interval is large.

Comment: Which kind of functions do you have ? A method for every function cannot work because functions can heavily oscillate.

Comment: @Peter $f(x)=m(\sin^2(\frac{n}{x}\pi)+\sin^2(x \pi))-k$, where $m,n$ and $k$ are greater than $1$, $m$ is much greater than $k$ or $n$, and $1<k<5$.

Comment: @Peter I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Peter I also updated it with some ancillary details.

Comment: Are you looking for a method that is certain to give all roots?  Or a heuristic for finding as many roots as possible?  In terms of heuristics, there are a lot of things you can do.  A simple option is to seed the region with lots of initial conditions and then perform Newton's method for optimization on each initial condition.  Another option would be simulated annealing.  But I would be surprised if there exists a guaranteed method to solve this problem.

Comment: $m$ is not relevant for zeros.

Comment: @lhf You're right, it isn't. It just makes it easier for me to see on a graph, as for big $n$ (even as small as $3595$), there are so much minima, that it looks like there are roots everywhere. Big $m$ separates the minima, so the only minima that $f(r)<10$ are the roots.

Comment: @sasquires I don't want to find the roots within an interval, I want to find the number of roots within an interval.

Comment: @QuoteDave: $m$ has strictly no effect on the number of roots. You can discard it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok, I fixed it.

Comment: @sasquires I have updated my question with an edit. Is such a function possible then?

Comment: @QuoteDave I obviously had not thought through this particular problem before responding, as other answers have shown, but my comments still apply to the general problem (for arbitrary $f(x)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is guaranteed that, in any given interval, if $f'$ has $n$ zeros, $f$ has at most $n+1$, but I don't think there is a general rule that applies in all contexts (apart from Bolzano's Theorem)

Comment: Yes, but the problem with Bolzano's Theorem is that for my $f(x)$, there is no point where $f(x)<0$.

Comment: Then I think ou won't be able to say too much unless you find zeros for the function's primitve (lower bound) or derivaitve (upper bound)

Comment: For $f'(x)$, the roots are the extrema of $f(x)$. So, even though the roots are minima, there are a lot of extrema so it does not help much.

Comment: @QuoteDave Does the primitive of $f$ also have a lot of zeros? Because knowing both can help you set a boundary

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what a primitive is. Is it like an indefinite integeral? If so, is there a way to calculate it? Can you show me an example, for example, when $n=33$.

Comment: I have updated my question with an edit. Is such a function possible then?

Comment: @QuoteDave I think that David is suggesting you can just use standard methods to find the number of roots of $f'(x) = - \frac{n \pi}{x^2} \sin\left(\frac{2 n \pi}{x}\right) + \pi \sin(2 x \pi)$ and then use this to give an *upper bound* for the number of roots of $f$.  He is not saying that every extremum is a root.  The only advantage of working with the derivative here is that in general we expect it to change sign at its roots.  The disadvantage is that you only get an upper bound.

Comment: @sasquires I am actually ok with an lower bound, if such is possible, as seen in the edit.

Comment: @QuoteDave As David pointed out in a comment above, you would be able to get a lower bound by considering the number of zeroes of the primitive $\int^x f(t) dt$, but of course this is useless in this particular case, because $f(x)$ is positive everywhere so this integral will have at most one zero, so the resulting lower bound is trivial.

Comment: @sasquires Where would that one root be located? Also, how about if it was $m(f(x))-1$,where $m$ is big, so the function would be negative at some parts?

Comment: The root depends on the constant of integration.  It is arbitrary.  But a function which is everywhere increasing can have at most one root.

Comment: @sasquires What do you mean by "the constant of integration"?

Comment: The constant of integration is $C$ in the general expression for an indefinite integral, $\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$

Answer (score 0):

For your particular function, the roots occur where

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac nx=k,\\x=l\end{cases}$$ for integers $k,l$. This requires

$$n=kl.$$

If $n$ is prime, there are four solutions: $x=-n,x=-1,x=1,x=n$. Otherwise, you need to take into account all divisors of $n$, which can be found from its prime decomposition.

I doubt there is an easy way to count the roots in a given interval; this seems to be on the same order of difficulty as the distribution of the primes.

---

The particular case of $n=3595$ is simple: the solutions are

$$-3595,-719,-5,-1,1, 5, 719, 3595.$$

Note that rather than computing the number of solutions in $[a,b]$, you can count the solutions in $(-\infty,x]$ and deduce $[a,b]$ by subtraction.

Comment: Well, let's say $n$ is large; then finding the factors would be very computationally expensive.

Comment: @QuoteDave: I repeat "I doubt there is an easy way to count the roots in a given interval".

Comment: I see. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I have updated my question with an edit. Is such a function possible then?

Comment: @QuoteDave: I think you did not understand why it can't be done.

Comment: But my edit asks for a lower bound of the number of roots in an interval, can that not be done?

Comment: @QuoteDave: if you consider that factorization is too costly, drop it.

Comment: In your particular problem, I think that @YvesDaoust has basically given you the answer.  Just factor $n$ (which is trivial algorithmically, even if the computational time does not scale well for large $n$).  After that you have to figure out if there is any product of factors that can be in the interval $[a,b]$.  This can obviously suffer from combinatorial explosion for highly composite numbers, but I suspect that an algorithm for that problem is known and could be found through some googling.

Comment: @sasquires: my point is that with $n$ so high that factoring is problematic (quoting the OP), enumerating the divisors increasingly is a harder problem. Google cannot do miracles on open problems. Anyway, the only numerical example given by the OP is... $3595$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I made it clear that there could be high computational cost when I referred to combinatorial explosion.  I merely said that an algorithm for this problem probably *exists*.  The OP's question states "I will also accept an algorithm that can tell, within an interval [a,b], whether at least one root exists there."  I am arguing that your answer essentially meets this request already, so the OP should accept your answer.

Comment: @sasquires: I known that my answer tells the truth, but the OP most probably expect a closed-form formula, which I cannot provide.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Just a quick question: do you mean you don't know, or you don't want to tell me?

Comment: @QuoteDave: I am telling you that nobody knows !